# ngForm or plain HTML Form - variable length inputs using *ngFor

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to do a variable length input form for ticket sales at which point I want to build that many input forms for a name and a gender for the guest, but I cannot think of how to do the id which must be unique using this method. I am currently trying to use this and getting mad errors:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: Parser Error:
>   Unexpected token = at column 24 in [let guest of guests; i = index] in
>   SellTicketComponent@315:22 ("" #f="ngForm">
>                  -->
>                    ]*ngFor="let guest of guests; i = index">
>                      
>                 "): SellTicketComponent@315:22 Parser Error: Unexpected token = at column 24 in [let guest of guests; i = index] in
>   SellTicketComponent@315:22 ("  ]id="{{guest[0]}}"
>                               [(ngModel)]="guest[0]"
>                               na"): SellTicketComponent@320:28

```
     <h5>How many tickets would you like? </h5>
     <input type="number" name="numGuests" min="1" max="10" [(ngModel)]="numPeople">

    <div *ngIf="numPeople > 1">
      <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
       <!--<div ngModelGroup="eventCreationData">-->
         <div *ngFor="let guest of guests; i = index">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label> Full name of guest: </label>
             <input type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    id="{{guest[0]}}"
                    [(ngModel)]="guest[0]"
                    name="{{guest[0]}}"
                    required>
           </div>
       <!--</div>-->
         <div class="form-group">
           <label> Gender: </label>
           <select
             class="form-control"
             id="{{i}}"
             [(ngModel)]="guest[1]"
             name="{{i}}"
             required>
             <option *ngFor="let i of genders">
               {{i}}
             </option>
           </select>
         </div>
       </div>
     </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `let` is missing

```
<div *ngFor="let guest of guests; let i = index">
```

Comment: Haha woops, I thought it was something more fundamental like you cannot use string interpolation in the id field or something. Thanks it works now